# Expected primary expression before "else" DevC++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the error "expected primary-expression before "else"" in this portion of the code. I however cannot find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//create class Date object today
Date today (monthT, dayT, yearT);

// check today date that it is correct
if(!(today.checkDate(monthT, dayT, yearT)))
cout << "Today's date is wrong!" << endl;
return 0;
else

//increment date to get tomorrow
cout << "Tomorrow is " << monthT << ", " << dayT+1 << ", " << yearT << "." << endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the braces:

```
//create class Date object today
Date today (monthT, dayT, yearT);

// check today date that it is correct
if(!(today.checkDate(monthT, dayT, yearT))) { //<---
    cout << "Today's date is wrong!" << endl;
    return 0;
} else //<---

//increment date to get tomorrow
    cout << "Tomorrow is " << monthT << ", " << dayT+1 << ", " << yearT << "." << endl;
```

Comment: @user3741550, Because without them, only one statement is part of the `if` branch. If you want to get technical, `if` is only ever followed by one statement. A group of statements surrounded by braces is a single statement called a compound statement, or block.

Comment: @user3741550 I think it is related to a parsing problem/issue, if you  want to know more take a look to the **dangling-else** problem.